# Repeating same rows from two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

**1) empDetails**

```
Field(id,section,name,domain)
Records('E_01','IT','RAN','AUTOMATION')
Records('E_01','IT','SAMU','EMBEDED')
Records('E_02','MECH','RAJ','AUTO')
```

**2) empAddress**

```
Field(id,section,address)
Records('E_01','IT','BANGALORE')
Records('E_01','IT','BANGALORE')
```

My query is

```
SELECT  t1.name,t1.domain,t2.address
FROM empDetails as t1 ,
     empAddress as t2
WHERE t1.id = 'E_001'
  AND t2.id='E_001' 
  AND t1.section = 'IT'
  AND t2.section = 'IT'**
```

But I am getting repeating rows as given below:

```
RAN AUTOMATION BANGALORE
RAN EMBEDED BANGALORE
SAMU AUTOMATION BANGALORE
SAMU EMBEDED BANGALORE
```

How to fetch correctly?

I need

```
RAN AUTOMATION BANGALORE
SAMU EMBEDED BANGALOR
```

Please anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see any **repetition** in your output - those are **four distinctly different rows** that get returned..... so what **exactly** do you want?? Why these two lines - and not the other two??

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.name, t1.domain, t2.address
from empDetails as t1, empAddress as t2
where t1.id = 'E_001' and t2.id='E_001' and t1.section = 'IT' and t2.section = 'IT'
```

The problem is the `from ..., ...`. Using a comma like this does a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), but you probably want an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join).

```
select t1.name, t1.domain, t2.address
from empDetails as t1 INNER JOIN empAddress as t2
ON --join condition goes here
where t1.id = 'E_001' and t2.id='E_001' and t1.section = 'IT' and t2.section = 'IT'
```

Comment: Hi Brenda,Thanks.i used this inner join query now.
But still am getting repeating records.

Comment: @shree - What is your new query? Please add it to the end of your question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t1.name,t1.domain,t2.address
  FROM empDetails as t1
 INNER JOIN empAddress as t2
    ON t1.id=t2.id
 WHERE t1.id = 'E_001'
   AND t2.id='E_001' 
   AND t1.section = 'IT'
   AND t2.section = 'IT'
 GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: hi If I use groub by, I am getting last record only.Only one record only diplaying

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT t1.name,t1.domain,t2.address
  FROM empDetails as t1
 INNER JOIN empAddress as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
 WHERE t1.section = 'IT'
   AND t2.section = 'IT';
```

Comment: No.I am getting still samething